# Call environment variables inside an ejs script

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, ejs

I need to use a process variable inside my ejs template in order to call an endpoint, but from this context I cannot reach the process nodejs variable.

How can I achieve this?

```
<a class="imgLink" href="#" onclick="get_user_info()">
    <div style="border: 2px solid gray;padding: 8px">Info</div>
</a>    
<script>
        function get_user_info() {
            $.get(`/users/${process.env.userId}`, function(data) {
                // Do something
            })
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Just a remark for best practice, your Environment variables shoul have capitalized name, in your case: 'uSER-ID' .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<a class="imgLink" href="#" onclick="get_user_info()">
    <div style="border: 2px solid gray;padding: 8px">Info</div>
</a>    
<script>
        function get_user_info() {
            var userId= '<%= process.env.userId %>';
            $.get(`/users/${userId}`, function(data) {
                // Do something
            })
        }
</script>
```

get the userId using <%= process.env.userId%>

Comment: It works but <%= process.env.userId %> should have quotes ```var userId= '<%= process.env.userId %>';```

Comment: What about just `$.get('/users/<%= process.env.userId %>', function (data) { ... })`?